# Multiple Excel tabs/worksheets to charts (dynamically)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file in the following format:

- Each tab/sheet contains data from a specific date (the sheet name)
- Column A contains various items

  - For each item I would like to create a line graph
  - Not all sheets contain all items
  - Items are not necessarily in the same order
- Column C contains the value (a float)
- Column B is the units of C (never saw this change)
- Columns D and E contain upper/lower expected range for C (range occasionally changes)

I would like to have a sheet with charts for all values, updated dynamically whenever a new data sheet is added.

Bonus if I could set a few items as "pinned" while the rest I could choose from a drop-down. Would also be nice to be able to display range lines.

I am able to create a pivot table and chart from multiple sheets (Alt+D, P) but that doesn't contain the date (sheet name). I also seem unable control the axis too much (but my Excel knowledge is poor at best).

I assume I would need some VBA function for that. Any pointers?

**EDIT (example)**

Below is a tiny example of how the data looks like. Hope it helps.

[image: A tiny example of how the data looks like]

Comment: Can you share an example file?

Comment: I cannot see an option to add a file. I added an example snippet to the question.